# iptables not blocking, bridged router

Tags: iptables, firewall, openwrt

Iptables is not blocking connections to devices connected to a bridged router. I have inserted the rules at the top of the rules list with: `iptables -I INPUT -d 216.58.201.46 -j DROP`

**Result:**

```
root@OpenWrt:~# iptables -L INPUT -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source            destination
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       216.58.201.46        0.0.0.0/0
0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            216.58.201.46
127 14720 delegate_input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0     0.0.0.0/0
```

I am still able to ping the IP from my laptop connected to the router with the rules, though I cannot ping the IP directly from the router as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INPUT table is for packets whose destination is your OpenWRT router itself. Use the FORWARD table for packets going through your router to/from your devices.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -d 216.58.201.46 -j DROP
```